# R, dplyr: assign number of occurence as value to column at several group_by() levels

Tags: r, count, dplyr, reshape2

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)

set.seed(8)
df <- data.frame(
  group = sample(c("A","B"), 10, replace=T),
  subgroup = sample(c("a", "b", "c"),10, replace=T),
  value = runif(10, -1,1)
  )
df %>% arrange(group,subgroup)
```

gives:

```
         group subgroup      value
1      A        a -0.1841505
2      A        a  0.3265360
3      A        a -0.8045035
4      A        b -0.5526222
5      B        a  0.2238653
6      B        a  0.0552373
7      B        b  0.2297515
8      B        b -0.5700525
9      B        b  0.6347312
10     B        c  0.9550054
```

I can indicate whether value is high or low, eg:

```
df2<-
df %>% mutate(reg = ifelse(value > 0, "high", "low"))
df2
```

gives:

```
   group subgroup      value  reg
1      A        b -0.5526222  low
2      A        a -0.1841505  low
3      B        b  0.2297515 high
4      B        b -0.5700525  low
5      A        a  0.3265360 high
6      B        c  0.9550054 high
7      A        a -0.8045035  low
8      B        a  0.2238653 high
9      B        a  0.0552373 high
10     B        b  0.6347312 high
```

Problem:
I would like to get columns `low.group`, `high.group`,`low.subgroup` and `high.subgroup` indicating how many times high and low values are found at the group (I thought of `dplyr`'s `group_by(group)` and `n()`, perhaps with `summarise()`) and at the group+subgroup level (`group_by(group, subgroup)`). This would generate a 6 row by 6 column data frame (combinations of A/B and a/b/c, and columns `group`, `subgroup`, `low.group`, `high.group`,`low.subgroup` and `high.subgroup`). First column should read (A, a, 3, 1, 2, 1), second (A, b, 3, 1, 1, 0) etc.
I can make counts e.g. by:

```
df %>%
group_by(group,reg) %>%
mutate(n.group=n())
```

But how do I split `n.group` into the two columns `low.group` and `high.group`. Same problem for the subgroups.

I am sure the functions in `plyr`, `dplyr` and `reshape2` can do this combined counting and summarization but how?

UPDATE:
Here is the hand-made result that I would get:

```
group   subgroup    low.group   high.group  low.subgroup    high.subgroup
A   a   3   1   2   1
A   b   3   1   1   0
A   c   3   1   0   0
B   a   1   5   0   1
B   b   1   5   1   2
B   c   1   5   0   1
```

Comment: I feel that it would be handy if one could create column names directly in `dcast()` .

Comment: Have you tried `spread` from `tidyr` package? You can (and have to) define the column names there

Comment: Did not known `tidyr`. Will check it out.

Comment: Providing the expected output would make it easier to help

Comment: Sure, I made the first two rows in result dataframe by hand above. Will give the whole data frame in 1 min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit lengthy, but seems to do what's expected:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(value > 0, "high", "low")) %>%
  group_by(group, subgroup, value) %>%
  mutate(sub = n()) %>%
  group_by(group, value) %>%
  mutate(grp = n()) %>% 
  distinct(group, subgroup, value) %>% 
  gather(key, val, sub:grp) %>%
  unite(x, value:key, sep = ".") %>%
  spread(x, val, fill = 0)

#Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
#
#  group subgroup high.grp high.sub low.grp low.sub
#1     A        a        1        1       3       2
#2     A        b        0        0       3       1
#3     B        a        5        2       0       0
#4     B        b        5        2       1       1
#5     B        c        5        1       0       0
```

Note that the combination A-c doesn't occur in the sample data and hence is not present in the output.

Comment: Yeah it does except I still need all rows. I will look at the tidyr pckg and try mingle with your suggestion.

Comment: I wonder if there would be a solution were the four columns (`high.grp`, ...) are created through 4 `mutate`assignments ? Is there a way to within a `mutate` assignment (or similar) make something like a `group_by` and `n()` ?

Answer (score 0):

A variation on docendo discimus's solution - using more reshape2 and less tidyr - is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)

df %>%
 mutate(value=ifelse(value > 0, "high", "low")) %>%
 group_by(group, subgroup, value) %>%
 mutate(sub = n()) %>%
 group_by(group, value) %>%
 mutate(grp = n()) %>%
 gather(key,val,sub:grp) %>%
 mutate(val.key=str_c(value,".",key)) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 dcast(group+subgroup~val.key, value.var="val", fill=0)
```